# AngularJS Custom date of birth input does not show required error

Tags: angularjs, html

I am making a date of birth type of input element which has no calendar view. i.e. user fills the date by typing.

**Code**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('birthDatePicker', [ function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                model: '=ngModel',
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                //SET CURSOR POSITION
                var setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
                    if (element[0].setSelectionRange) {
                        element[0].focus();
                        element[0].setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
                    } else if (element[0].createTextRange) {
                        var range = element[0].createTextRange();
                        range.collapse(true);
                        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
                        range.moveStart('character', pos);
                        range.select();
                    }
                };

                // RESET VALIDATION ERRORS
                var resetErrors = function() {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('pattern',true);
                };

                if (!ngModel) return;
                var d1, d2, m1, m2, y1, y2, y3, y4, cursorPos, dateString, parsedDate;
                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {
                    var digits = inputValue.split('').filter(function (s) { return (!isNaN(s) && s != ' '); });
                    d1 = digits[0] ? digits[0] : 'd';
                    d2 = digits[1] ? digits[1] : 'd';
                    m1 = digits[2] ? digits[2] : 'm';
                    m2 = digits[3] ? digits[3] : 'm';
                    y1 = digits[4] ? digits[4] : 'y';
                    y2 = digits[5] ? digits[5] : 'y';
                    y3 = digits[6] ? digits[6] : 'y';
                    y4 = digits[7] ? digits[7] : 'y';
                    dateString = d1+d2+'/'+m1+m2+'/'+y1+y2+y3+y4;

                    resetErrors();

                    if(dateString == 'dd/mm/yyyy') {
                        ngModel.$viewValue = '';
                        ngModel.$render();
                        return ngModel.$viewValue;
                    }

                    ngModel.$viewValue = dateString;
                    ngModel.$render();
                    cursorPos = digits.length + 2;
                    if(digits.length < 3) {
                        cursorPos = digits.length;
                    } else if (digits.length < 5) {
                        cursorPos = digits.length + 1;
                    }

                    setCursorPosition(cursorPos);

                    parsedDate = new Date(ngModel.$viewValue);

                    // validation for correct date
                    if(isNaN(parsedDate.getTime())){
                        ngModel.$setValidity('pattern',false);
                        return ngModel.$viewValue;
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('pattern',true);
                    }

                    return ngModel.$viewValue;
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate>
  <input ng-model="date" name="question"
             placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" birth-date-picker type="tel" autocomplete="off" required>
  <p ng-show="myForm.question.$error.required">Date is Required</p>
  <p ng-show="myForm.question.$error['pattern']">Date is incorrect</p>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
```

The problem is with displaying error message. The message `Date is required` is displayed only first time and if submit button is pressed. It does not work when the user clears the input value by pressing `backspace` key.

**Update:**
On the lower version of `AngularJS`, it is working just fine as what I wanted, but with `AngularJS 1.5.8`, I am having bad luck. :(

Please help me tackle this problem.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I works just fine ! I don't see any question or problem here ...may be I didn't quite get ur question can u elaborate ?

Comment: @Angular_10 Yes, functionality works perfect. But there is a small issue, follow these steps - 1. start filling the date, 2. clear the field by pressing backspace, 3. You should see a message "Date is required" but you don't see it actually, unless you press submit button.

Comment: Yea, I just observed that! Well in that case what you can do is catch hold of backspace event with ng-keydown and write a function in your directive which will set the respective message.It worked for me !

Comment: @Angular_10 Thanks, what you said is working at my end also but I will wait for concrete solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages and the example on that page, this is how you should use ng-messages...

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('birthDatePicker', [ function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                model: '=ngModel',
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                //SET CURSOR POSITION
                var setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
                    if (element[0].setSelectionRange) {
                        element[0].focus();
                        element[0].setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
                    } else if (element[0].createTextRange) {
                        var range = element[0].createTextRange();
                        range.collapse(true);
                        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
                        range.moveStart('character', pos);
                        range.select();
                    }
                };

                // RESET VALIDATION ERRORS
                var resetErrors = function() {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('pattern',true);
                };

                if (!ngModel) return;
                var d1, d2, m1, m2, y1, y2, y3, y4, cursorPos, dateString, parsedDate;
                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {
                    var digits = inputValue.split('').filter(function (s) { return (!isNaN(s) && s != ' '); });
                    d1 = digits[0] ? digits[0] : 'd';
                    d2 = digits[1] ? digits[1] : 'd';
                    m1 = digits[2] ? digits[2] : 'm';
                    m2 = digits[3] ? digits[3] : 'm';
                    y1 = digits[4] ? digits[4] : 'y';
                    y2 = digits[5] ? digits[5] : 'y';
                    y3 = digits[6] ? digits[6] : 'y';
                    y4 = digits[7] ? digits[7] : 'y';
                    dateString = d1+d2+'/'+m1+m2+'/'+y1+y2+y3+y4;

                    resetErrors();

                    if(dateString == 'dd/mm/yyyy') {
                        ngModel.$viewValue = '';
                        ngModel.$render();
                        return ngModel.$viewValue;
                    }

                    ngModel.$viewValue = dateString;
                    ngModel.$render();
                    cursorPos = digits.length + 2;
                    if(digits.length < 3) {
                        cursorPos = digits.length;
                    } else if (digits.length < 5) {
                        cursorPos = digits.length + 1;
                    }

                    setCursorPosition(cursorPos);

                    parsedDate = new Date(ngModel.$viewValue);

                    // validation for correct date
                    if(isNaN(parsedDate.getTime())){
                        ngModel.$setValidity('pattern',false);
                        return ngModel.$viewValue;
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('pattern',true);
                    }

                    return ngModel.$viewValue;
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate>
  <input ng-model="date" name="question"
             placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" birth-date-picker type="tel" autocomplete="off" required>
<div ng-messages="myForm.question.$error" role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required">Date is Required</div>
      <div ng-message="pattern">Date is incorrect</div>
</div>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: error messages are always being shown when running code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying bad approach of wrapping ng-model.
Try [Ben Nadel approach](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2756-experimenting-with-ngmodel-and-ngmodelcontroller-in-angularjs.htm), it should illuminate problem.